# Mount partition on KVM guest and host at the same time

Tags: linux, filesystems, partition, kvm-virtualization

Is there a way to mount a partition on the kvm host and one guest at the same time?

(on linux / ubuntu, no samba suggestions, please)

Answer (score 3):

A normal filesystem will be corrupted if you mount it from multiple OS's at the same time. A cluster file system should work.

The easiest solution is probably to use NFS.

Comment: I think nowdays with SSHFS, well it's better. https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win